# What cause Orbeon Forms to do an endless revalidate on an XForm till it get a stackoverflow

Tags: orbeon

I am using Orbeon Forms CE version orbeon-4.0.0.M11.201210030654-CE.

I had an XForm (XHTML) with multiple instances, and I did a bind with required="true()" on one of the instance and use xxforms-invalid & xxforms-valid to toggle cases. Below are some code samples from my xform.

```
<xforms:instance id="teaching-load-instance" src="oxf:/apps/uis-common/model/uis-teaching-load-xforms-instance.xml"/>

<xforms:bind nodeset="instance('teaching-load-instance')/teaching_load">
    <xforms:bind nodeset="module_id" required="true()"/>
</xforms:bind>

<xforms:action ev:event="xxforms-invalid" ev:observer="teaching-load-instance">
    <xforms:toggle case="invalid-form-case"/>
</xforms:action>

<xforms:action ev:event="xxforms-valid" ev:observer="teaching-load-instance">
    <xforms:toggle case="valid-form-case"/>
</xforms:action>
```

When accessing this xform page, a stackoverflow error will be thrown.

Here are the debug logs from orbeon.log file.

```
2012-10-23 21:42:42,470 DEBUG XFormsServer  -         start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "month-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,470 DEBUG XFormsServer  -           start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,470 DEBUG XFormsServer  -           end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,470 DEBUG XFormsServer  -         end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,470 DEBUG XFormsServer  -         start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "verification-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,470 DEBUG XFormsServer  -           start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,470 DEBUG XFormsServer  -           end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,470 DEBUG XFormsServer  -         end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,470 DEBUG XFormsServer  -         start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "modules-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,471 DEBUG XFormsServer  -           start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,471 DEBUG XFormsServer  -           end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,471 DEBUG XFormsServer  -         end dispatching {time (ms): "1"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,471 DEBUG XFormsServer  -         start dispatching {name: "xxforms-invalid", target: "teaching-load-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,471 DEBUG XFormsServer  -           start handler {name: "xxforms-invalid", phase: "target", observer: "teaching-load-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,471 DEBUG XFormsServer  -             interpreter - start executing {action name: "xforms:action"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,471 DEBUG XFormsServer  -               interpreter - start executing {action name: "xforms:toggle"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,471 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                 start dispatching {name: "xforms-revalidate", target: "xf-2"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,471 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                   start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,471 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                     validation - start performing revalidate {model id: "xf-2"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,471 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "triggers-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,471 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,471 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,471 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,471 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "parameters-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       end dispatching {time (ms): "1"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "check-user-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "main"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "temp"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "session"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,472 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "status-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       end dispatching {time (ms): "1"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "month-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "verification-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "modules-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                       start dispatching {name: "xxforms-invalid", target: "teaching-load-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                         start handler {name: "xxforms-invalid", phase: "target", observer: "teaching-load-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                           interpreter - start executing {action name: "xforms:action"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,473 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                             interpreter - start executing {action name: "xforms:toggle"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,474 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                               start dispatching {name: "xforms-revalidate", target: "xf-2"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,474 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                 start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,474 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                   validation - start performing revalidate {model id: "xf-2"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,474 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "triggers-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,474 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,474 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,474 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,474 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "parameters-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,474 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,474 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,474 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,474 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "check-user-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,474 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,474 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     end dispatching {time (ms): "1"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "main"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "temp"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "session"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "status-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,475 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "month-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,476 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,476 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,476 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     end dispatching {time (ms): "1"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,476 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "verification-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,476 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,476 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,476 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,476 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "modules-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,476 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,476 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,476 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,476 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                     start dispatching {name: "xxforms-invalid", target: "teaching-load-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,476 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                       start handler {name: "xxforms-invalid", phase: "target", observer: "teaching-load-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,476 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                         interpreter - start executing {action name: "xforms:action"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,476 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                           interpreter - start executing {action name: "xforms:toggle"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,477 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                             start dispatching {name: "xforms-revalidate", target: "xf-2"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,477 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                               start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,477 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                                 validation - start performing revalidate {model id: "xf-2"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,477 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                                   start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "triggers-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,477 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                                     start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,477 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                                     end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,477 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                                   end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,477 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                                   start dispatching {name: "xxforms-valid", target: "parameters-instance"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,477 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                                     start performing default action {}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,477 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                                     end performing default action {time (ms): "0"}
2012-10-23 21:42:42,477 DEBUG XFormsServer  -                                                   end dispatching {time (ms): "0"}
```

Comment: The same issue also occurs on Orbeon Forms 3.9.0 CE

Answer (score 1):

You *can* create infinite loops in XForms, but in this case you seem to have hit a bug in the XForms engine. The `xf:toggle` should have no effect if the case hasn't changed. I filled [an issue](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/513) for this, which you can track.

This issue is fixed since Orbeon Forms 4.0 M13. With earlier versions, you can work around it by adding an `if` on the `xf:toggle`. Assuming your switch id is `my-switch`:

```
<xforms:toggle if="xxforms:case('my-switch') != 'invalid-form-case'"
               case="invalid-form-case"/>
```

Plus an equivalent `if` added to the other `<xforms:toggle case="valid-form-case"/>`.

Comment: This is now [fixed](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/513) and the fix will be in 4.0 M13.

Comment: Thank you. Any ideas when 4.0 M13 will be made available for download.

Comment: It most likely be pushed out today (2012-10-30). When it is up, it will be announced on our http://blog.orbeon.com/ and on Twitter https://twitter.com/orbeon.

Comment: Thank you. We tested M13 with our applications, and it did fix the infinite loop - revalidation.